# Can't load an assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASPNetCore app I'm using reflection to create an instance of a class. I'm using the following line of code to get the assembly I need:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
```

I keep getting the same error saying 'Could not load a file or an assembly C:\Users\theRestOfThePath. Access denied'

I'm on Windows 7 and I suppose the problem has to do with security policy, but being a beginner programmer I don't know how to cope with the issue. Could anyone give me a hint on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to access the assembly that's *currently executing*?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You haven't provided much context for your question.  ie. I don't know if you're writing a console application or if it's class library.  I also don't know anything about the class you're trying to instantiate.  Is that class in the same *project* as the code you're writing to instantiate it?

Comment: My solution consists of three projects. One is AspNetCore project which contains all the controllers and services. The other two projects are class libraries. In one of my controllers I'm trying to instantiate a class which has been defined in one of the class libraries. The Factory class which is responsible for the creation of objects has been defined in the same project as the class I'm trying to instantiate. Might that be a problem?

Comment: I challenge you to re-evaluate your decision to create an instance of your class via reflection.  This sounds to me like a gratuitous use of reflection.  If you don't use reflection here, you bypass the reason for your question entirely.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Just allow Everyone the right to read & execute the folder contains your dll.

Comment: @tuanv2t Just did. BUt still getting the same exception.

Comment: please check the assemblyPath if it ends with the dll file or not, example mylibrary.dll then assemblyPath look like C:\Users\hero\mylibrary.dll